# ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>. how to solve this issue?

Tags: html, angular

```
ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>.
```

Angular expected this DOM:

```
<app-root _nghost-ng-c2816335483="">
   <html lang="en">…</html>
   <-- AT THIS LOCATION
   …
</app-root>
```

Actual DOM is:

```
<app-root _nghost-ng-c2816335483="">
   <meta _ngcontent-ng-c2816335483="" charset="UTF-8">
   …</meta>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
   …
</app-root>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>TodoListNew</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   </head>
   <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post some of your code please